# Use directional light with WireframeHelper

Tags: three.js

I used THREE.MeshLambertMaterial and set wireframe: true in the previous version of ThreeJS, it worked well.

But after I update to r69, it looks strange.

[image: strange wireframe]

And I tried to use WireframeHelper to fix this problem, but it can not use directional light now. After examining the source code, I think the reason is that WireframeHelper is using LineBasicMaterical. Is there other solution to add directional light on it?

Thanks.

Comment: The strange look when `material.wireframe` is `true` is clearly a bug. Is your geometry `BufferGeometry`?. What loader did you use?

Comment: I use STLLoader, and the loader returns BufferGeometry.

Comment: Would you like to file a three.js bug report? It appears that `material.wireframe` does not render correctly when the geometry is `BufferGeometry` in r.69.

Comment: According to the article (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4627), it seems that we are suggested to use WireframeHelper in the future.

Comment: Can you try loading and converting to regular geometry `geometry.fromBufferGeometry()`.

Comment: It works well! Thanks for your advice. I use Geometry instead.